# Ionic wifi enabled/disabled detection

Tags: ionic-framework, wifi, detection

I'm quite new to Ionic development and I have a question. Is it possible to detect if Wifi is enabled on the phone. 
1. Is this possible for iOS?
2. Is this possible for Android?
Do I need a plugin for it and what are good ones?

I work with Ionic 3.

Kind regards,

Stefan

Comment: See: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/check-network-connection-with-ionicframework/

Answer (score 0):

There is a cordova plugin available for it. Install the plugin and just do 
navigator.connection.type to fetch the network state. Below is the official document of this plugin.
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information

Below is the ionic document about usage of this plugin
http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: One more question about this plugin. It seems that i only can check whether there is a Wifi connection or not. When there is no Wifi connection there are 2 possible causes:
1. No wifi is available
2. Wifi is switched of in the device (in ios or android settings)
My question is:
Is question was/is: Is it possible to read the ios or android setting. I want to warn the user when wifi is disabled in the settings

Comment: Haven't tried that and nothing mentioned about it in the documents.